# When I click to open a ViewPage or a ViewUserControl Visual Studio 2008 hangs for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, viewusercontrol, viewpage

When I double click on a ViewPage or a ViewUserControl in Visual Studio 2008 the whole application hangs for me, I have no idea why...

The only error log I can find in the Event Log is this:

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A035E00) (80131506)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling the hex error (7A035E00) and/or the version number 2.0.50727.3063 brings up some promising results.

The most likely fix appears to be to reinstall the .NET framework.

http://www.techdreams.org/microsoft/fixing-the-error-net-runtime-version-20507273053-fatal-execution-engine-error-net/370-20080926

Make sure you are using the latest version of the .NET framework.  The 2.0 version is available at [Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&displaylang=en), and the 3.5 version is available at 
[Download Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325FD-AE52-4E35-B531-508D977D32A6&displaylang=en)